# Generate an adapted and measurable process from a $\max$ function.

Tags: stochastic-processes, compactness, stochastic-analysis, measurable-sets

Given a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$, where $\mathcal{F}$ is a natural filtration generated by a $\mathbb{R}$-valued process $(X_t)_{0 \le t \le T}$ under the Wiener measure $\mathbb{P}$. Given a Borel measurable function $f: \mathbb{R} \times K \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, where $K$ is a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$, we define a function $g(x) = \max_{y \in K} f(x,y)$.

Can we construct an $\mathcal{F}$-adapted and measurable process $(\alpha_t)_{0 \le t \le T}$ from $(g(X_t))_{0 \le t \le T}$ such that $g(X_t (\omega)) = f(X_t(\omega), \alpha(\omega))$$\mathbb{P}$-a.s.$?$

My attempt: By Axiom of choice and compactness of $K$, we may define a process $(\alpha_t(\omega))_{0 \le t \le T}$  $\mathbb{P}$-a.s. I am confused to show the process is adapted and measurable. The process is adapted intuitively by the construction but I have no idea how to prove this rigorously. Please add more conditions if needed.

Comment: I think this is basically equivalent to arguing that you can find a measurable function $h(x)$ such that $g(x) = f(x,h(x))$.  Such a function clearly exists by the axiom of choice, but measurability is not clear.  Also, when you say "measurable process," what notion of measurability do you mean?  I'm guessing progressively measurable?

Comment: @user6247850 Thanks for the reply. The measurability I used is $\mathcal{B}([0,T])\otimes \mathcal{F} \rightarrow \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is measurable. If a process is measurable and adapted, then it has a progressively measurable modification.